# Проблема при работе с сокетами в Android

Tags: java, android, сокет

При проблемах с интернет соединением, получается что он ожидает данные, но данные не приходят и соединение зависает. Как сделать так, чтоб при проблемах с соединением он закрывал соединение?
 Ниже приведен  код клиента на android:

```
 static String  getMsg(InputStream in)
    {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024]; 
        String temp="";
        try {
            in.read(buffer, 0, 4);
            int n=bufferToInt(buffer);// переводит буфер в число
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                in.read(buffer, 0, 4);//считывает данные
                char a=toSymbol(bufferToInt(buffer));//переводит в символ
                temp=temp+a;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return temp;

    }
```

Зависает на `in.read()`.

Comment: либо делать чтение с таймаутом, либо (если можете влиять на протокол) - делать ping-pong - то есть, каждые несколько секунд/минут посылать спецзапрос, на который другая сторона должна немедленно ответить.

Comment: А как делается чтение с таймаутом?

Comment: перед чтением нужно вызвать метод [setSoTimeout](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) и обрабатывать исключение java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо вызывать метод [setSoTimeout](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)), при задержке будет выбранено исключение `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

Comment: скопировали мой комментарий?